# Need help using the SCP command line

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, scp, cp

I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04

I want to transfer my website to a new server.

**Here are my questions :**

How to copy files with png extension ? I tried the following command line but it doesn't work :

```
$ sudo scp -r -p root@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/www-example-com/web/*.png/ /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/
```

How to copy the following folder excluding a folder inside ?

```
$ sudo scp -r -p root@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/www-example-com/web/themes/custom/ /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/themes/custom/
```

I want to exclude the below folder from the above folder :

```
/var/www/www-example-com/web/themes/custom/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old/node_modules/
```

Comment: See here for the same question about scp excluding a dir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121337/recursively-use-scp-but-excluding-some-folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your `scp` command "does not work"; can you give more information on that? I'm sure the command outputs *something*. Could you share that?

Anyway, your top command has a superfluous `/` in it. `/` is the character in Linux that is used as directory separator. So `/home/mathieu/` would be "directory mathieu inside directory home". Files do not end with a `/`.

Instead of
`sudo scp -r -p root@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/www-example-com/web/*.png/ /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/`...

...try to write
`sudo scp -r -p root@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/www-example-com/web/*.png /home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/`
(Notice the lack of `/` after `*.png`.)

On a sidenote: only prefix commands with `sudo` if you really need to run that command as super user. In this case, if your current user is owner of `/home/ubuntu/www-example-com/web/`, `sudo` is not needed. If you make a mistake in a command and used `sudo`, this might go horribly wrong. Ranging from "Oh well, I can live withouth that file anyway" to "Oh shoot - this is going to take a reinstall" or worse.

About the second question (on excluding a subdirectory), I have no fitting answer.

Comment: OK, thanks. SUDO is in danger of breaking the source or the destination ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to exclude a directory from a copy is to move the directory somewhere else first.  You can move it back after the copy - it's just two move commands.